# How To Add Function Level Authorization to Azure Http Trigger Java Function

Tags: azure-functions, postman, azure-java-sdk, azure-http-trigger

I've Created Http Trigger Azure Java Functions, Function Name 1.FUNCTION (FUNCTION LEVEL Authorization)

,,,
package com.function;

```
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpMethod;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpResponseMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpStatus;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;

import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class Function {
    /**
     * This function listens at endpoint "/api/HttpExample". Two ways to invoke it using "curl" command in bash:
     * 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your host}/api/HttpExample
     * 2. curl "{your host}/api/HttpExample?name=HTTP%20Query"
     */
    @FunctionName("FUNCTION")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                name = "req",
                methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
                authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION)
                HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        // Parse query parameter
        final String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        final String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);



        if (name == null) {
                return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
            }

    else {
                return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name).build();
        
                }
        }
    }
```

,,,

Above Function Having Function Auth.
Successfully Deployed to Function app and I've Updated Host Key& Value

**In Function App**:

[image: host key& value in Function App Image]

But This Function Not Working In Postman Even I use Host key and Value

**In Header Section Through Postman**

[image: Function Error Screenshot in Postman]

Postman Error: 401Unauthorized

Please Guide me is it right way to use FUNCTION Level Authorization For azure Java Function or need to ADD/change any Things in Code/Function App Level?

Answer (score 0):

- Well if you go to `Functions` tab and click on the function which you have deployed.

[image]

- Then click on the `get function url`  tab and copy the url .

[image]

- Now this URl would include the function key which can be used for auth

PostMan output
[image]

Comment: Hi Mohit, please read my question again.... I m asking Authorization not working